Apple Hardware test booted from a USB stick not working on Mid 2012 McBook Pro
I have a mid 2012 Macbook Pro running OS Catalina.
Using these instructions at Github, I have made a USB stick with Apple Hardware Test on it.
This process worked for me previously as I have done with a 2011 Macbook Pro running High Sierra and other even earlier machines and OS x's.
With this 2012 MBP, the volume appears on 'option' boot manager but when I select it the machine scrolls very briefly in script and then it just boots my normal OS.
I have even managed to put the .diagnostics file back into Core Services but using the 'D' startup key it only starts internet diagnostics. I would like to know why this Mac ignores the USB volume and won't run the contents of the USB stick?

Welcome to Ask Different. I’m not sure why you say Catalina won’t boot from a diagnostic volume or alternate OS since that’s purely firmware and setup and hardware. Do you mind if I edit this so it’s more likely to make sense? If you revert the edit, that’s totally fine, just perhaps explain how that OS is relevant to your preparations.

Hi Bmike. Is it okay to respond to your question here ? No I don't mind if you edit the question and I see that you have anyway. Thanks!

Excellent! I try to be extra careful and warn people and in my case, I made light changes but think you might have much better refinements to add after some consideration.
